# Classic ASP check if an element in array exist

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, split

I have the below code, i want to check if index 3 in array is existing or not, but i always  got this error :

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'
>   Subscript out of range: '[number: 0]'

```vb
urlArray=Split(url1,"/")

If (not isNull(urlArray(3))) then
    If (urlArray(3)="site") Then
        newUrl=urlArray(0) &"/"& urlArray(1) &"/"& urlArray(2) &"/m/" & urlArray(4) & "/" & urlArray(5)
    Else
        newUrl= url1
    End If
Else 
    newUrl= url1
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Use function "IsArray" to make sure that variable is array, see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/isarray-function-HA001228862.aspx):

   > IsArray returns True if the variable is an array; otherwise, it
   >   returns False. IsArray is especially useful with variants containing
   >   arrays.
2. Use function "UBound" to check upped bound of array, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhx59d0t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

   > Returns the largest available subscript for the indicated dimension of
   >   an array. UBound(arrayname[, dimension])
   >   The lower bound for any dimension is always 0.

Comment: thanks I used UBound to check if the array has elements or not :) .